# Map doesn't sort with regard to comparator c++

Tags: c++, mingw

I'm trying to solve a issue where I'm inserting chars in to a map of type `<char, int>`. If the char already exists in the map I will increase the int by 1. I have created my own comparator for prioritizing the elements within the map.  The priority doesn't work in the way I hope it would work since in the end the output doesn't follow the order.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

struct classcomp {
  bool operator()(const int& a, const int& b) const {
        return a < b;
    }
};

bool isPresent(map<char,int,classcomp> mymap, char c){
    return (mymap.find('b') != mymap.end());
}

int main(){
    string input="dadbadddddddcabca";
    map<char,int,classcomp> mymap;
    char temp;

    for(string::iterator it = input.begin(); it!=input.end(); ++it){
        temp = *it;
        if(!isPresent(mymap, temp))
            mymap.insert(pair<char,int>(*it,1));
        else
            mymap[temp]++;
    }

    for (auto& x: mymap) {
        cout << x.first << ": " << x.second << '\n';
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Gives the following output:

```
a: 4
b: 2
c: 2
d: 8
```

Comment: Maps are sorted according to key. Your comparison doesn't do anything different to the default comparison for `char`.

Comment: The comparator is for sorting keys, not values.

Comment: The keys appear to be correctly sorted: `a, b, c, d`.

Comment: Also your `isPresent` has a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::map is designed to be sorted by key, and providing comparator for type of value does not change anything. imagine you have `std::map<char,char>`, how would you think you can provide comparator for value (if it would be possible)?
So solution would be to use container that allows to sort by multiple keys like boost::multi_index or just create another map - reversed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string input="dadbadddddddcabca";
    map<char,int> mymap;

    for(string::iterator it = input.begin(); it!=input.end(); ++it){
        mymap[*it]++;
    }
    map<int,char> reversemap;
    for (auto& x: mymap) {
        reversemap.insert( make_pair( x.second, x.first ) );
    }

    for (auto& x: reversemap ) {
        cout << x.first << ": " << x.second << '\n';
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Notice that your pre-check for element existance is completely redundant, std::map operator[] creates new element and initializes it, if it does not exists.
You may notice that in output you are missing some values now (though they are sorted), if that is not what you need, change reversemap type from map to multimap, which allows key duplicates.

Comment: "reversemap[x.second] = x.first;" isn't a good idea, because some `seconds` could be equal

Comment: hmmm... can't see... AFAIK `reversemap[x.second] = x.first;` is equals to `reversemap.insert( make_pair( x.second, x.first ) );`

Comment: @borisbn not for multi_map look into my suggestion after the code.

Comment: IMHO changing `map` to `multimap` in your code (and maybe remove appropriate suggestion) will be a good idea ? Isn't it ?

Comment: @borisbn probaly, but that would have different behavior than original intention of OP if I can call that intention. I think this way OP could learn difference btw std::map and std::multimap better and why he/she needs one or another.

Comment: I agree. Moreover, that SO offers to stop discussion or to move it to chat ))

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26504/discussion-between-borisbn-and-slava)

Answer (score 2):

The comparator is used to sort the `char`s and not the `int`s.

It is sorting the keys and seems to work just fine - `a b c d`.

Comment: Comparator **can** compare `ints` while container contains ("the butter is buttery" as we - Russians say))) `chars`

Comment: I wanted to take of my downvote, but SO say that I can't unless you edit your answer. Please, make any changes to it

Comment: @borisbn - Thanks. I moved my comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`map` sorts its entries by key, not value.  The `char` keys get silently cast to `int` in your `classcomp::operator()`

Answer (score 1):

Why

```
mymap.find('b') != mymap.end());
```

and not

```
mymap.find(c) != mymap.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you wanted

```
int main() {
    std::string input="dadbadddddddcabca";
    typedef std::map< char, int > map_t;
    map_t mymap;
    char temp;

    for ( std::string::const_iterator it = input.begin(), e = input.end(); it != e; ++it ) {
        temp = *it;
        mymap[ temp ] = mymap[ temp ] + 1; // Hopufuly operator[] inserts zero initialized value, if can't find a key
    }
    typedef std::pair< typename map_t::key_type, typename map_t::mapped_type > pair_t;
    std::vector< pair_t > sortedByValue;
    sortedByValue.assign( mymap.begin(), mymap.end() );
    std::sort( sortedByValue.begin(), sortedByValue.end(), []( const pair_t & left, const pair_t & right ) {
        return left.second < right.second;
        // change to
        // return left.second > right.second;
        // for descend order
    } );

    for ( const auto & x: sortedByValue ) {
        std::cout << x.first << ": " << x.second << std::endl;
    }    
}
```

[LWS link](http://liveworkspace.org/code/WizwG%245)